# UltiSnips shell/python interpolation and ${VISUAL}

Tags: python, shell, vim, ultisnips

I really can not figure how to do this.

I am trying to create a snippet that will read a file (the name I will get it by selecting it so it will be in the `${VISUAL}`) and then using grep extract a line from it.

What I tried is something like

```
!v cat ${VISUAL}  | grep "some text"
```

but of course that in shell `${VISUAL}` has a different value.

I tried something in python, but I am lost.    All I could get was

```
!p snip.rv=snip.v.text
```

that will give me the value for `${VISUAL}`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for your specific case you could use the vim builtin :read function ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite grep, but if you're okay with Python-style regex, you can do this:

```
`!p 
import re
from pathlib import Path
path = Path(snip.v.text)
content = path.read_text()
snip.rv = '\n'.join(re.findall(r'foo.*bar', content))
`
```